# Xamarin - support inserting GIF and images using Android keyboard

Tags: image, xamarin, keyboard, clipboard, gif

Has anyone gotten the android keyboard to support GIF and image insertion in an Xamarin app? Let's say I want to build a chat application, have a custom EditText view to capture user input, and want to have it behave similar to the Android built-in chat application. Currently the keyboard shows a popup [image: "[app] doesn't support image insertion here"]. Is it possible to make this work? I prefer to not create a custom keyboard renderer, though was hoping this could be done within a custom EditText renderer. Along the lines of:
[image: chat]

**UPDATE**: For anyone looking for a similar solution, I have been making progress using the https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/android-n/CommitContentSample. Essentially set the content mime types and wrap the IOnCommitContentListener, then process OnCommitContent().

Comment: *"...  were not added to Xamarin Forms"* Not sure what that means. You can't find that Android API, even when you are in Android custom renderer? You are doing some mix of "native Xamarin" (aka Xamarin.Android and/or custom renderers) and "Xamarin Forms"? I would think having a custom keyboard renderer would be the very first step you'd have to take. Or suppress the soft keyboard, write your own "view that looks like a keyboard" that you make appear on the form. Complete control over appearance and behavior.

Comment: @Stride 9 You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/?_ga=2.213677974.365333463.1676250549-1144270789.1675673660) with your solution(Updated section) and accept it as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem.